# How to set UISwitch state when receiving data from API

Tags: swift

I have a screen with Two UISwitch buttons.

I am receiving a data in API:

```
"CustomerSubscribed": [
        {
            "Customer_ID": "100132",
            "Mobile": "3213103428",
            "Subscription": "Bill Payment",
            "Mnemonic": "BILL",
            "IsActive": 0
        },
        {
            "Customer_ID": "100132",
            "Mobile": "3213103428",
            "Subscription": "Funds Transfer",
            "Mnemonic": "IBFT",
            "IsActive": 1
        }
    ]
```

These are my two switches:

```
private var fundSwitch: UISwitch = {
    let switchView = UISwitch()
    switchView.isOn = false
    switchView.onImage = UIImage(named: "switchOn")
    switchView.offImage = UIImage(named: "switchOff")
    switchView.onTintColor = UIColor.purple
    switchView.tag = 1
    switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchStateDidChange), for: .valueChanged)
    switchView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return switchView
}()

private var billSwitch: UISwitch = {
    let switchView = UISwitch()
    switchView.isOn = false
    switchView.onImage = UIImage(named: "switchOn")
    switchView.offImage = UIImage(named: "switchOff")
    switchView.onTintColor = UIColor.purple
    switchView.tag = 2
    switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchStateDidChange), for: .valueChanged)
    switchView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return switchView
}()
```

On the basis of isActive, I have to set the values of UISWitch. If it is true, then switch must be on, otherwise if it is false then it must be Off.

This is what im trying right now:

```
@objc func switchStateDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
     if sender.tag == Switch.fundTrasnfer.rawValue {
            print( sender.isOn ? customerSubscribe?[0].isActive ?? false: "Fund Transfer Switch is Off" )
        } else {
            print( sender.isOn ? customerSubscribe?[1].isActive ?? false: "Bill Payment Fund Transfer Switch is Off" )
        }
}
```

and another what I tried:

```
@objc func switchStateDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
     for customer in self.customerSubscribe! {
            if customer.isActive == true {
                print(sender.isOn ? "Switch is ON": "Switch is Off")
            } else {
                print(sender.isOn ? "Switch is ON": "Switch is Off")
            }
        }
}
```

these are two approaches I have tried. I am using VIP Architecture, and I received response here:

```
extension SubscriptionViewController: SubscribeViewProtocol {
    func saveSuccessCustomerData(response: CustomerSubscribeEntity.CustomerServiceResponse) {
        
    }
    
    func successSetupSubscription(response: SubscriptionEntity.SubscriptionServicesResponse) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("Id \(response.customerSubscribed?[0].customerID)")
            self.customerSubscribe = response.customerSubscribed
            
            self.fundTransferLbl.text = self.customerSubscribe?[0].subscription
            
            self.billPaymentLbl.text = self.customerSubscribe?[1].subscription
     
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created customerSubscribe to have the response in it:

```
    var customerSubscribe: [SubscriptionEntity.CustomerSubscribed]?
```

My screen:

[image]

UI Is is programmatically, and i have both fund and bill switch defined.

Can I make a loop and check too instead of comparing taking index?

Comment: This needs more information to be solved definetively. Of what type is `customerSubscribe` and how ist that type defined? `sender` suggests this is inside of some `@IBAction` but leaves much room for interpretation. Please add enough context for us to understand what you are trying to do. Please read [mre] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still hiding a lot of implementation detail that would be neccassary to give a definitive answer. So I have to make some assumptions.

1. `isActive` is of type boolean
2. `successSetupSubscription` lives in the same place as your switch vars
3. you create your switches programaticly and add them to your view.

Your function `switchStateDidChange` will react to changes done by the user. If you want to change the state of the switch programmaticly you need to set it to the switch itself.

```
func successSetupSubscription(response: SubscriptionEntity.SubscriptionServicesResponse) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("Id \(response.customerSubscribed?[0].customerID)")
        self.customerSubscribe = response.customerSubscribed

        self.fundTransferLbl.text = self.customerSubscribe?[0].subscription
        
        self.billPaymentLbl.text = self.customerSubscribe?[1].subscription
        //add this
        self.fundSwitch.isOn = response.customerSubscribed[0].isActive
        self.billSwitch.isOn = response.customerSubscribed[1].isActive
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked. I have used loop instead and made a check. Thumbs up

Comment: @AhmedSaeed if this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. This will help future readers to find the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
 switchOne.isOn = customerSubscribe?.first?.isActive == 1
 switchTwo.isOn = customerSubscribe?.last?.isActive == 1
```